# MYSQL Performance impact when use dbquery with where clause "1 = 1" with huge records

Tags: mysql, performance, where-clause

I am working for one mysql db query performance improvement task and i faced below one query where the "where clause is 1=1".

my question is, what is different in term of performance for executing time of below two db query

1. `Select * from Table1 where 1=1`
2. `Select * from Table1`

> nos of records : 159954 for table1 for one client
>
> nos of records :2452798 for table1 for second client.

and in some cases, this table is joined with another table with same where clause `1=1`.

can mysql query compiler optimize this query while execution ?

Version of MySQL Server 5.1

Comment: I would suggest a simple time analysis. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501876/how-to-get-the-execution-time-of-a-mysql-query-from-php

Comment: tomas, without getting relative answer, how would i accept it ? if i accepted any answer, does it means not more response ?

Comment: @javaamtho http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134070/175151

Comment: possible duplicate of ["where 1=1" statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, it looks same but my concern here is about the performance impact my database. i do not work on dynamic query impl.  as said how mysql optimiser work on "1=1"..

Answer (score 1):

Both are same as both will fetch all records and so no such big difference. Here `1 = 1` will always be true.

```
1)Select * from Table1 where 1=1  

2)Select * from Table1
```

See this other posts on same topic

[Importance of WHERE 1 in MySQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983655/importance-of-where-1-in-mysql-queries)

["where 1=1" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149142/where-1-1-statement)

Comment: Rahul, thanks for quickly reply but in term of nos records are huge. would it make any different ?

Comment: That's what I mentioned `NO`; as both the queries are logically same. They will fetch all `N` records.

Comment: ok :) , So whats about the "IN" operator with single value and "=" operator ? i have validated this and found little ms different in performance.. whats your opinion ?

Comment: I have never tested but `where col1 IN (val)` and `where col1 = val` will surely not make huge performance difference; since implicitelu your DB engine will flatten that `in(val1)` to a OR'ed stack.

Comment: @javaamtho, consider accepting it as an answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

The two queries return the same set of rows, and they will have identical run time.

The reason `1=1` is often used is to simplify the process of producing computer-generated `where` clauses; optimizers of all non-toy RDBMS engines ignore this condition as `true`. Search around on Stack Overflow for explanations of how `1=1` helps with generated queries.

Answer (score 0):

Put explain before your query or turn on query profiler and you'll find out. I'd imagine 1=1 would be an extremely small overhead, barely noticeable.

Comment: i have seen some milisecond impact on execution of my dbquery with where clause "1=1" and i suggest, it should ignore it if really not required.

Answer (score 0):

For those that did computer architecture, I think we would all agree that there is less computing if you changed WHERE 1 = 1 to WHERE true.  Less involved with the registers and no need for the compiler to token up 1 = 1 into smaller calculations.

So in the case where you are building up a query and for simplicity you need to have that first condition the query might look like this:

SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE true AND UserID = 1

Really we are talking very very small computations here.  Unlikely to save you the amount of computations needed just from posting this stack overflow question.