# Query performance alternatives

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve records from two tables and group them by date. I use a LEFT JOIN to get the data but I was wondering whether I should use

```
DISTINCT DATE(t1.date)
```

or

```
GROUP BY DATE(t1.date)
```

Which one is faster?

Comment: This post will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/581521/whats-faster-select-distinct-or-group-by-in-mysql

Comment: well...  there is that: [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164319/is-there-any-difference-between-group-by-and-distinct)

Comment: Those ^ but personally I'm always a fan of testing it myself. In PHP I would use something described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501876/how-to-get-the-execution-time-of-a-mysql-query-from-php and compare both the queries, give them a very large sample size to really highlight the differences.