# get Sybase ASE server messages via PHP

Tags: php, odbc, sybase, sap-ase

I need to get time of script execution in my PHP code. On a database client I can use:

```
set statistics time on
```

And I would see messages like:

```
   W (1): Parse and Compile Time 0.
   W (2): Adaptive Server cpu time: 0 ms.
   W (3):  
   W (4): Execution Time 0.
   W (5): Adaptive Server cpu time: 0 ms.  Adaptive Server elapsed time: 0 ms.
```

I'm using `odbc-driver` to connect to Sybase and `odbc_connect/odbc_exec` to execute query. Can I get these messages in my PHP code? Or I should set time manually using `declare @time_start` etc.. or setting time in php code before and after query execution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way of getting the ASE execution timings back to PHP via the ODBC driver. I assume you are using PDO_ODBC driver in PHP. Have you tried using a different driver? Others may have such a feature implemented. Maybe the official [Sybase PHP Extension Module](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01693.1570/doc/html/car1308847162829.html) can help you out here.

My recommendation is using some PHP snipped to keep track of the execution time as you already suggested. You can find a nice example in this Question here: [How to get the execution time of a MySQL query from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501876/how-to-get-the-execution-time-of-a-mysql-query-from-php)